# React-Redux with Materialize inputs validation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a React-Redux with react-materialize project which I need to apply different validations
on the inputs on button click.

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to itterate 
over all the inputs and test for particular validation.

In jQuery I would do someting like

```
<input data-validation="required" />
$("[data-validation='required']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
        error = true;
        message = "input is required"
    }
});
```

How would I do this in React?

"Snippit of code below, code has been cut down to only relevant information"

```
      onSubmit() { //This is where I want to validate }


      render() {    
        return (
            <form className="z-depth-4">
                <Row>
                    <Input
                        s={6}
                        label="Company or Trading Name"
                        id="company_name"
                        name="company_name"
                        value={this.props.formData.company_name}
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                        validate
                        required="required"
                        aria-required="true"
                    />
                    <Input
                        s={6}
                        label="Contractor Name (if different to the above)"
                        id="contractor_name"
                        name="contractor_name"
                        value={this.props.formData.contractor_name}
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                        validate
                        required="required"
                        aria-required="true"
                    />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Input
                        s={12}
                        l={6}
                        label="Trade license number"
                        id="trade_licence"
                        name="trade_licence"
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                        validate
                        required="required"
                        aria-required="true"
                    />
                    <Input
                        s={12}
                        l={6}
                        label="NSW Fair Trading contractor licence"
                        id="contractor_licence1"
                        name="contractor_licence1"
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                        validate
                        required="required"
                        aria-required="true"
                    />
                </Row>
                ...
                <Row>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <button
                            className="btn waves-effect waves-light"
                            type="submit"
                            name="action"
                            onClick={this.submitform}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                   </div>
                </Row>
            </form>
        );
     }
```

Comment: do you have any of your react code showing the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be something like this.

You can declare a local state in your container component to hold some flags for the errors:

```
constructor () {
  this.state = {
    errors: {
      companyName: false,
      contractorName: false,
      tradeLicence: false,
      contractorLicence1: false
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could have a function that can be called inside `onSubmit()` that can perform validation:

```
performValidation = () => {
  const {
    company_name,
    contractor_name,
    trade_licence,
    contractor_licence1
  } = this.props.formData

  this.setState({
    errors: {
      companyName: company_name.length === 0,
      contractorName: contractor_name.length === 0,
      tradeLicence: trade_licence.length === 0,
      contractorLicence1: contractor_licence1.length === 0
    }
  })
}
```

When rendering the input you could do something like this:

```
render () {
  const { errors } = this.state
  const { formData } = this.props

  return (
    ...
      <Input
        ...
        value={formData.company_name}
        className={errors.companyName && 'has-error'}
      />
    ...
  )
}
```

That would be the gist of it. If you have a lot of fields and you don't feel like doing all this manual work we can figure out a solution to iterate through the `formData` properties and generate a map of corresponding errors and then put them in the local state but it would still require some work.